# Passing ajax data to blade to use in php query

Tags: php

I have a modal which opens on click:

```
  jQuery('.calendar-day-update-edit-trigger').click(function(event){
        var targetDate = jQuery(this).attr('data-day');
        jQuery('.updater-date-edit').html(targetDate);
        jQuery('.hidden-date-input-edit').val(targetDate);
        $.ajax({
         method: "get",
         url: "/admin/days/getdata/"+targetDate,
         data:  { 'EID': targetDate,},
         })
      });
```

I want to send the data to a blade file so I can query my database.

```
public function getData($getData){
      $data = Day::where('sale_at', $getData)->first();
      return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Blade file is just a template, which shows data. Controller is responsible for selecting data from db. So, __what__ is your question?

Comment: I have a modal, which is populate by inline php. How do I send target data to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

If you want to return data from your controller to your template, you must return your data in json.

After this, you can use the success method in your ajax call to get the data from your controller and affect these data to an or more HTML elements in your blade template.

In your JS:

```
   $.ajax({
     method: "get",
     url: "/admin/days/getdata/"+targetDate,
     data:  { 'EID': targetDate,},
     success: function(data) {
        $('#your_html_element').val(data);
     }
   })
```

In your PHP:

```
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($data);
```

In your blade template:

```
   <div id="your_html_element"></div>
```